# React Navigation access to other screen methods

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

I would like access to a method in my first screen class with React Navigation. Like when you press button on screen B, the script call `ScreenA.refreshStuff()` but i don't know how to access to this...

Answer (score 2):

Screen A

```
this.props.navigation.navigate("ScreenB", {function: refreshStuff})}
```

Screen B

```
const { refreshStuff } = this.props.navigation.state.params;
```